# How can I load a 3d model to an IOS app, and scale/transform/rotate it to place on an image?

Tags: ios, 3d, glkit

I should load a 3d model (let's say a fridge) and scale or rotate it to locate on a kitchen photo (just for an example).

I have seen several SDKs but all was for 3d games. What I need is to put and play with my object in a native IOS app.

Where should I start? GLKit is the answer for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 3d rendering is made by OpenGL ES, that is a pretty difficult topic. Apple provides GLKit to help developer to integrate OpenGL ES but none of is a model parser or scene manager, is hard anyway. I can suggest you to use a 3d engine, I took a look at two engines: 
1-Nineveh GL
2-Irrlicht
The first integrate absolutely fine in iOS projects and exposes objective c API. It uses only OpenGl 2.0 shaders. The problem is that is a beta version. 
The latter is written in C++ and supports both 1.0 and 2.0, but is pretty hard to integrate.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I heard about Nineveh. I will try it. Do you think that I can export models from Solidworks and load into the 3d engine?

Comment: Check which format are supported by Nineveh and you'll find that probably you will need to export in DAE or something elese